# IE 6 width = 70% for a pop up div with dynamic data not working

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-6, width

I want to display a pop div that has dynamic data to the center of the screen. I specified height = 300px
and width = 70% and overflow scroll:y.

In IE7/IE8 the div renders properly to the center of the screen in specified dimensions and scroll occurs if the data size doesn't fit.

But in IE6 width = 70% not working at all. The div width varies as per the size of the data. Since its dynamic data its not in our control and sometimes pop up wont render at all if we go for high resolution.

What will be a fix for this? Any input is highly appreciated.

```
<div id="outerDiv" class="panelDialog" style="position:absolute; display:none; width:70%;">
<div id="div2" title="Search Provider">
    <a href="#" id="href1" title="Close">
       <img id="img1" title="Close" alt="Close" />
    </a>Search Popup
</div>
<div id="div3">
        <div style="height: 300px; overflow-y:  scroll;">               
            <TABLE>
                <TR>
                    <TD width="100%"></TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
            <input type="reset" value="Close" id="btn1" name="nae1" class="commandExButton" />              
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jim, please post the code or a JSFiddle.

Comment: <div id="outerDiv" class="panelDialog" style="position:absolute; display:none; width:70%;">

<div id="innerDiv" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;">
 
<table width="100%">
  <p>dynamic data</p>
</table>

</div>
</div>

Comment: Why use a table? That's your problem I'd say.

Comment: Also the markup is invalid. You need `<tr>` and `<td>`.

Comment: I have to display tabular data with rows and columns inside this div.

Comment: I showed example snippet, the dynamic table is something like this  <table width="100%"> <tr> <td>data</td></tr></table>.

Comment: Can you post a complete example in the question, not comments please? Don't put real data, but do put columns and everything. Also, what DOCTYPE are you using?

Comment: Jim, does setting `width="100%"` on the `table`, `#div3` and the child `div` with overflow change anything?

Comment: Use cellpadding and cellspacing 0, have no border.

Answer (score 1):

I think that IE6 is choking on this... from the comments above

`<table width="100%">`

> the dynamic table is something like this `<table width="100%"><tr><td>data</td></tr></table>`

Reset that as a lower percentage or as a pixel unit and see if the problem disappears.